# When to use indexing vs `get` for dicts in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed that for the standard `dict` in Python, there are two ways to get an element from the dictionary:

```py
# First we create a `dict`:
my_dict = {'greeting': 'hello'}

# And now we can read from it, as such:
my_greeting = my_dict['greeting']  # `my_greeting` is now 'hello'.

# But this also works:
my_greeting = my_dict.get('greeting')  # `my_greeting` is now also 'hello'.
```

The only difference that I can find is that for a key that doesn't exist, indexing throws a `KeyError`, while `get` silently fails and returns `None`.

It seems to me that this makes no difference in practice, because with indexing one needs to use `try/except` and with `get` one needs to use `if/else` to check for a missing value. (In my experience a variable ending up being `None` means that at some point you need to handle this much like you'd handle an error, it's hardly ever intentional).

If anything, indexing seems more Pythonic: "Errors should never pass silently, unless explicitly silenced". Unless you count using `get` as "explicitly silencing" which seems absurd, an error passing silently seems to be exactly what it does.

But that then begs the question: Why is there such a thing as `get` for a `dict`, and when is it ever appropriate to use it?

Comment: Just one small example when it's useful: Implementing a counter: `d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why is there such a thing as get for a dict, and when is it ever appropriate to use it?*

You might provide `get` with second value, which will be provided if key was not found for example

```
dct = {"A":1}
value = dct.get("B",0)
print(value)
```

output:

```
0
```

This is useful, when using default value for non-present keys makes sense.